# JLink: export java modules in separated files

Tags: java, java-9, java-module, java-platform-module-system, jlink

With JLink, I'm able to build my application with a tiny JVM. For now, the build is monolithic: all the java modules are melt inside one file (which can be extracted with jimage):

```
jlinkImage/
└──lib/
   └──modules
```

Now, I'd like to make incremental builds: when I deploy my application, I would like to only upload modules that changed since the last release.

**Can JLink be configured to export the different java modules in separated files?**

e.g.

```
jlinkImage/
└──lib/
   └── moduleA
   └── moduleB
   └── moduleC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a deeper look on this question:

**A rough answer is no**. 
This is not the purpose of JLink, it only serve to build a tight JRE.

However, the JRE produced by JLink can still be extended with external modules. Here a simple way to separate modules in different files:

1. Produce a minimal JRE with jlink, e.g.:

`jlink --add-modules java.base,java.xml --output minimalJre`

2. Add some module jars inside the minimalJre:

```
minimalJre/
└──modules/
   └── moduleA
   └── moduleB
   └── moduleC
```

3. Launch it with:

`bin/java -p modules/ <other args>`